# How to count items by range

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following EF6 entity:

```
public class Evaluation {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Double Value { get; set; }
  public Double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following model:

```
public class EvaluationStats {
  public Int32 LowCount { get; set; }
  public Int32 NormalCount { get; set; }
  public Int32 HighCount { get; set; }
}
```

I need to fill an EvaluationStats where:

```
LowCount = Number of Evaluations where Weight * Value < 10
NormalCount = Number of Evaluations where Weight * Value >= 10 and <= 15
HighCount = Number of Evaluations where Weight * Value > 15
```

I was trying the following:

```
context
  .Evaluations
  .Select(x => new { Stat = x.Value * x.Height })
  .GroupBy(x => x.Stat)
```

But how to group by range so I can count by range?

**UPDATE**

In some cases I might have more than three items so I changed to an Enum:

```
public enum EvaluationLevel { VeryLow, Low, Normal, High, VeryHigh }
```

And then I create the stats using a IDictionary:

```
IDictionary<EvaluationLevel, Int32> EvaluationLevelStats
```

So I would have 5 items in this dictionary ... But I might have more.

In other situations I might have, for example, 8 levels.

Is it possible to query the database once and fill this dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You have to work out the range each one belongs in. I would probably do something like:

```
context
  .Evaluations
  .Select(x=> new {
    Range = (x.Value * x.Weight < 10) ? "Low": ((x.Value * x.Weight <= 15)? "Normal": "High"),
    Stat = x.Value * x.Weight
  }.GroupBy(x => x.Range);
```

Comment: The problem I see with your answer is it becomes confusing when using many levels ... I update my question to use a IDictionary<EvaluationLevel, Int32> which I would fill ... It seems better to hold the data but is it possible?

Comment: One thing you could do for the situation where you have more than 3 groups, is create a grouping method of your own that knows how to perform your grouping, and then rather then grouping by in the query, just select stat out of the table, and then leave it to your code after the query to sort. As far as making EF do it from within the query, I am fairly certain your only option is to do as I suggested above.